How do I split a comma separated string into an array and map to multiple HL7 segments using JavaScript?
I am attempting to convert a single JSON field into multiple HL7 NTE segments based on the number of comma separated values.
Example:
JSON Input
"caseComments" : "+ ABC, + CBA, + CAB",

HL7 Output
NTE|1|+ ABC|
NTE|2|+ CBA|
NTE|3|+ CAB|

Number of comma separated values changes per message
Normally the JSON has multiple separate segments with an individual value in each and I can split based on a predetermined number of values.
But, I am unsure how to take the string split it into an array with different amounts each time and map each value to a single NTE each.

"map each value to a single NTE each" -- Use the map() method of arrays. The callback function receives the array elements and their indices. You can use the index to produce the NTE|#| part of the result.

You can tweak this for your specific json object, but here's a possible solution for you:

Split the string by commas.
Trim any whitespace
Iterate the array while generating NTE
segments with an index.

Some code for you to consider:


const jsonData = {
  "caseComments": "+ ABC, + CBA, + CAB"
};

// Split, trim, and transform into NTE segments
const nteSegments = jsonData.caseComments.split(',')
  .map((comment, index) => `NTE|${index + 1}|${comment.trim()}|`);

// Log the result
nteSegments.forEach(segment => console.log(segment));




You can spare the extra forEach loop if you do the transformation to NTE ... in the map

good suggestion; i've implemented it
